# How to Delay between Two frames in Frame-By-Frame Animation

Tags: android, animation, scale

Now I have four Images and I have applied frame animation on these four images

1.one

2.two

3.three

4.Go

I want to give a time delay between three and Go frame which would be a random time.

Here is my code

```
int d=5000;
AnimationDrawable drawable=new AnimationDrawable();
    drawable.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.one), 1000);
    drawable.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.two), 1000);        
    drawable.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.three),d);      
    drawable.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.go),d);
    drawable.setOneShot(true);
    iv3.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    drawable.start();
```

Where iv3 is my ImageView

And I also want to give Scale animation with frame-by-frame animation on these images.

Please Help me out...

Th@nks

Comment: Isn't `d` a random value which you could pass in your addFrame()? Or is that not working?

Comment: no d is simply an integer value I dont have any problem regarding to it.....I want to give delay between two frames

Comment: ok but i will make it random value but my problem is to how to apply delay between two frames means i should see nothing(no frmae of animation) when three image goes and before go image come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Searching and doing lots of online stuff I believe that I cannot give delay time between two subsequent frames in frame-by-frame animation and I also cannot implement scale and frame-by-frame together.So I carried out the other way is following

```
    b=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scalealpha);
a=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scalealpha);
        c=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scalealpha);
        e=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scalealpha);

                a=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.scalealpha);
                iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
                iv3.startAnimation(a);

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {

                public void run()
                {

                       iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);  
                       iv3.startAnimation(b);
                       Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {

                                   iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
                                   iv3.startAnimation(c);
                                   Handler handler = new Handler();
                                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {

                                               iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.go);                                                                  
                                               iv3.startAnimation(e);
                                        }}, 3000);

                            }}, 1000);


                }}, 1000);
```

If anyone know better way than this please tell me and I would be glade to know..........
Thanks to whom who tried to solve this problem.....

Answer (score 1):

see this it works fine for me.

```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ImageView view;
AnimationDrawable Anim;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAnimation);
    view.setId(1);
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (view.getId() == 1) {
                animationStart();
                view.setId(2);
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
                view.setId(1);

            }
        }

        private void animationStart() {
            try {
                BitmapDrawable frame1 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.one);
                BitmapDrawable frame2 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.two);
                BitmapDrawable frame3 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.three);

                BitmapDrawable frame4 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.four);
                BitmapDrawable frame5 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.five);
                BitmapDrawable frame6 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.six);

                Anim = new AnimationDrawable();
                Anim.addFrame(frame1, 200);
                Anim.addFrame(frame2, 200);
                Anim.addFrame(frame3, 200);
                Anim.addFrame(frame4, 200);
                Anim.addFrame(frame5, 200);
                Anim.addFrame(frame6, 200);
                Anim.setOneShot(false);
                view.setBackgroundDrawable(Anim);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        Anim.start();

                    }
                }, 100);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example : [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

It seems that you have to write the animation duration in XML like:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0" android:duration="50" />
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** : check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) link too.

Comment: no not animation duration the duration I have already defined in code the numeric values(I have done this animation using coding not by xml).But I want to give random delay between two frame...

Comment: do u know how to give scale animation with frame-by-frame animation to these images?????